# Creating temp files in scripts: Advantages of mktemp over touch-ing a file?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

Although I can achieve creating a temp file with either `mktemp` and `touch`, how specifically does `mktemp` benefit reliability and/or security in scripting over just manually `touch`ing a file?

Comment: @MarcB The original question appears to be asking about the `mktemp` command as would be used in a shell script. This is safe. It's the `mktemp` library function as would be used in a compiled program which isn't safe. And that has nothing to do with how modern the OS is, it was never safe it just wasn't realized originally.

Comment: Can someone add a comment explaining why this does not meet the guidelines - it's not obvious to me and probably is not obvious to many others who come across it.

Comment: @mtraceur I think the reason this was closed is some folks did not realize this is actually useful information for anyone writing Unix shell scripts (i.e. programming). They treated this as if it was requiring information about MS Word or Excel!

Comment: Discussed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/how-can-an-attacker-use-a-fake-temp-file-to-compromise-a-program

Comment: The original author of the mktemp command, Todd C. Miller, has written this: https://www.mktemp.org/readme.html

Comment: @ErwanLegrand 404 error; [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20211114102721/https://www.mktemp.org/readme.html).

Comment: Updated link: https://www.mktemp.org/docs/readme/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`mktemp` randomizes the name. It is very important from the security point of view.

Just imagine that you do something like:

```
echo something > /tmp/temporary-file
```

in your root-running script.

And someone (who has read your script) does

```
ln -s /etc/passwd /tmp/temporary-file
```

before.

This results in `/etc/passwd` being overwritten, and potentially it can mean different unpleasant things starting from the system becomes broken, and ending with the system becomes hacked (when the input `something` could be carefully crafted).

The `mktemp` command could help you in this situation:

```
TEMP=$(mktemp /tmp/temporary-file.XXXXXXXX)
echo something > ${TEMP}
```

Now this `ln /etc/passwd` attack will not work.

*A brief insight into the history of mktemp*: The `mktemp` command was invented by the OpenBSD folks, and first appeared in OpenBSD 2.1 back in 1997. Their goal was to improve the security of shell scripts. Previously the norm had been to add `$$` to temporary file names, which was absolutely insecure. Now all UNIX/Linux systems have either `mktemp` or its alternatives, and it became standard de-facto. Funny enough, the `mktemp` C function was deprecated for being unsecure.

Comment: I disagree. A root running script which puts sensitive data in /tmp ought to make sure it creates the file with sufficiently restrictive permissions in the first place; even with mktemp an "attacker" could keep scanning /tmp for readable files. Security is not the main purpose of mktemp; it's to ensure multiple instances of the same program don't clobber each others temporary files.

Comment: @Lqueryvg: Of course it is a security measure. Please take a look at CWE-377 and "Temporary Files - CERT Secure Coding Standards" from CERT and many other docs related to the topic

Comment: The original question is why use mktemp over just creating files using
"say" the touch command. The answer is to avoid name collision - which can lead to unpredictable behaviour and data corruption (e.g. if two instances of your script run at the same time). Of course security has to be considered too, but it's not the raison d'etre of mktemp.

Comment: @Lqueryvg: If you create a file in a directory with 1777 permissions (temp) you *must* always keep security considerations in your head

Comment: @IgorChubin if /tmp/temporary-file already exists, wouldn't ln throw an error saying that /tmp/temporary-file already exists?

Comment: @Lqueryvg Delete your comments. They are **harmfully** wrong. `mktemp` adds security because `touch foo`, `>foo`, and `>>foo` are all unsafe against link races. Users who can make links can then write to arbitrary files as the user running the script. This can enable all sorts of exploits. If the script is ran by root, on many systems that includes privilege escalation! **If you don't see why or how that is, post a question**. But those comments are causing and validating continuing use of a dangerously insecure practice. Delete them.

Comment: @lee-gaines No, that's precisely the problem. `touch`, `>`, and `>>` do not error if the file exists. The very purpose of `touch` and `>>` is to work on files that already exist (they just happen to also create files that don't, because for the jobs they are meant do, that's good design). The purpose of `>` is to create "new" files, but in a **content-centric** way: it will open an existing file and delete all of its contents. Though some shells do have a "no clobber" option you can turn on for `>>` and `>` to error out on existing files.

Comment: @Lqueryvg You *are* correct in situations where **1)** all shells that will run the script have "no clobber" as an option, **2)** your script turns it on, and **3)** every developer who looks at that script remembers these conditions. But otherwise **there is no truly secure way to "create a file with sufficiently restrictive permissions"** in the shell itself. Compared to alternatives, `mktemp` 1) is more portable and 2) makes it less possible and less automatic to be done in ways that create liability for machine or human error to produce code that loses the security it provides.

Comment: No, I will NOT delete my comments. I have a right to a voice the same as anyone else here. Also, saying that my comments are harmful is ridiculous. I did NOT say that security is not important; if anything I said the opposite.  Use cases will exist where developers care about the security of the temp files and others where they don't. But to say that the primary reason for using `mktemp` is security is quite simply wrong. That's why I commented on this answer.

Comment: @Lqueryvg your first comment is irrelevant, as far as security is concerned. The problem is *not* with writing sensitive data in /tmp. You got that wrong. The security problem here is that is allows overwriting the content of arbitrary files. I'll see if I can improve the answer as admittedly is does not explain clearly enough what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Lqueryvg comments like yours is half of what makes StackOverflow dangerous... with the other half being those who believe the first thing they read without digging a bit more. The manpage for mktemp continualy mentions safety, protection, attacks and security, FFS. Thank you to those who gave context!

Comment: @ErwanLegrand: absolutely! I wonder how is it possible that the comment has so many upvotes eventhough it is completely irrelevant, and has nothing do to neither with the question, nor with the answer

Comment: The mktemp command was invented by the OpenBSD folks. Their goal was to improve the security of shell scripts. Previously the norm had been to add $$ to temporary file names. See http://man.openbsd.org/mktemp.1 You might want to add this information to your answer @IgorChubin.

Comment: When I started writing shell scripts, the mktemp command did not even exist. At that time, the only secure way was to set umask properly then run mkdir then check the return value of mkdir.(This works because mkdir() is atomic.) And just everybody was getting this wrong. As a result, TOCTOU races were all over the place. This is why the mktemp command was added by the OpenBSD developpers.

Comment: @ErwanLegrand: A good idea! Done

Comment: Saying that it was created by OpenBSD and for security .... does not seem to be correct considering that `mktemp` has existed before OpenBSD - it is at least 20 years older and had for most of the time not had security as a main-focus. Its primary use is still to provide an easy way to get unique tmp-files to avoid file-collisions and does so with appropriate permissions.

@mtraceur - if anything is harmful it is your behavior here.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf `mktemp` *the C function* existed at least [in UNIX v7](https://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/3/mktemp), but was insecure (ToCToU race + overwhelmingly predictable file names). *A* command named `mktemp` existed at least [in HP-UX 7.0](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_hp9000hpux0ReferenceVol1Section1Sep89_33991967/09000-90013_HP-UX_7.0_Reference_Vol_1_Section_1_Sep89_djvu.txt) but the interface was different and insecure by default (you'd need to know to pass the `-c` option and put quality randomness in LOGNAME, at least). OpenBSD 2.1 introduced today's more secure `mktemp` command.

Comment: (Also, the HP-UX manages leave this ambiguous, but everything about that manpage/interface is strong evidence that you'd also need to think to set `umask` to a secure-for-what-you-are-doing value before calling it, whereas OpenBSD's `mktemp` was written so that the file/directory comes into being with secure minimal permissions regardless of your file creation mask.)

Comment: openBSD improved it but it still existed before that and was not primarily concerned with security.
If i would create another version that stores the data on a remote server - would you then say that `mktemp` was created for cloud-storage?

Comment: @ABaumstumpf if your `mktemp` was 1) created primarily for the cloud storage benefits and 2) became *the* `mktemp` (so that every `mktemp` CLI on a modern OS was implementing *your* `mktemp` interface/functionality/behavior rather than any prior `mktemp`), then *yes* I would, and that would be correct unless someone was explicitly asking about previous historical programs or other interfaces that happened to have the same name.

Comment: @hmijail, "with the other half being those who believe the first thing they read without digging a bit more." --- As one of those of this half I can say I have dug a bit deeper and now I see I've made a mistake upvoting Lqueryvg's comments. It is indeed a matter of security. Unfortunately I can't undo my upvotes :(

Answer (score 42):

You often want a "scratchpad file" (or directory).  Moreover, you might need several such files at the same time, and you don't want to bother figuring out how to name them so there's no conflict.

`mktemp` fits the bill :)

Comment: This is the most correct answer. This is not about security. The main reason is to ensure that multiple instances of the same
program or script (possibly run by the same or different users) 
do not over-write each other's temporary run-time data.

Comment: Anyone reading the above comment by @Lqueryvg: it is **dangerously** wrong in suggesting that there is no security benefit. See my comments on [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11636850/4372452) for why.

Comment: Sigh. I did NOT say that there was no security benefit.

Comment: The mktemp command was invented by the OpenBSD folks. Their goal was to improve the security of shell scripts. Previously the norm had been to add $$ to temporary file names. http://man.openbsd.org/mktemp.1

Answer (score 9):

One more extra reason: not all systems use `/tmp` as temporary directory.
For example [Termux](https://termux.com/) has a different long path due to technical reasons (it runs as processes inside Android):

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp
```

Scripts that create temporary files or directories using `mktemp` will be portable and also work in such special environments.

Answer (score 8):

Ok actually it is written clearly in man pages.

> mktemp - create a temporary file or directory.
>
> Create a temporary file or directory, safely, and print its name.

It create a file or directory safely means no other user can access it, that's why its permission is 600

> touch - change file timestamps

It simply change the timestamps of a file if already created and create a file if does not exist. But file permission is still 644 by default.

For more detail check following man pages:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp

http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch

Comment: No, safely also means that it mitigates against an attacker using links to overwrite arbitrary files!

Answer (score 1):

At least in the bash shell you can do something like:

```
dirpath="/tmp/dir1-$$/dir2-$$"  
mkdir -p $dirpath  
chmod -R 0700 /tmp/dir1-$$
```

for instance.

Comment: There is a couple of race conditions in this code, the first one before the call to mkdir and the second one between the mkdir an chmod commands. The proper way to do this is to run umask first, then run mkdir and then check the return value of mkdir. This is probably the best solution whenever the mktemp command is not available.