# Shell script execution without interruption

Tags: shell, unix

How can a sequence of commands in a shell script be executed without interruption by any other processes?

Comment: Don't interrupt them.

Comment: What kind of "interruption" do you mean?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, without being preempted ? No way. The kernel scheduler is free to choose which task to executed at any time.

However, on Linux, you can set a ``real-time'' priority (i.e., SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR) to be sure that the script won't be interrupted to execute lower-priority tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make a shell process ignore interrupts, or other signals, the answer is via the [`trap`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) command.

```
trap "" 2
```

or:

```
trap "" INT
```

To cancel that behaviour, don't list anything in the string:

```
trap 2
trap INT
```

If you need to remove temporary files on interrupt (and related signals), you can use something like:

```
tmp=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/name.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15   # EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM

...do operations using temporary files...

rm -f $tmp
trap 0     # Cancel the exit trap
```

The set of signals shown is a pretty comprehensive set, covering most normal events.  If you get sent SIGKILL (`kill -9`), the temporary will be left around — there is nothing you can do.  The `mktemp` command creates the file safely (see [Why do we need `mktemp`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636790/why-do-we-need-mktemp)), but actually leaves a tiny window of opportunity between when the file is created and the trap is set for the script to be interrupted and leave the temporary file lying around.